# How to exclude google adsense from contact us page?

Tags: wordpress, adsense, contactus

I would like to exclude google adsense which is in a floating bar from the contact us,home and privacy policy pages.The floating plugin has no option to do this.

This would be the page: http://elraffe.com/contact-us/

I tried many things already,but i am doing something wrong for sure.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the WordPress Conditional Tag `is_page`.

```
<?php if(!is_page('contact-us'){ ?>
<!-- Google AdSense Code Here -->
<?php } ?>
```

The above code checks if you are not on the Contact Us page, then proceeds to output the Google AdSense code.

**Reference:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: It might work in a single page,where i insert the adsense code manually,but in the plugin,have to put HTML adsense code.It will not break the code,but ignores it.